# Number of labeled regular graphs on n vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, oeis

What is known about the number of labeled regular graphs on n vertices?  The sequence does not appear to be in the OEIS.

Comment: Welcome to MO! Please include more details regarding what you want to know (exact numbers for samll values, bounds for somewhat larger ones, asymptotics [for which range of parameters])? Also, searching the internet one finds various information readily. I assume you already know quite a bit about the problem so it could be better to mention this so that people do not tell you things you already know.

Comment: Do you mean the number of labeled $k$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices for any $k$? If so, I think you'd find more results by specifying a particular $k$. For example, $2$-regular labeled graphs seem to be counted by [A001205](http://oeis.org/A001205). Also note that $3$-regular graphs are called _trivalent_. That helped me find [A006607](http://oeis.org/A006607).

Comment: Enumerating labelled regular (simple) graphs of fixed degree $k$ on $n$ vertices is a notoriously intractable problem. Equivalently, one is enumerating traceless $n\times n$ symmetric $(0,1)$-matrices with row and column sums $k$. The paper of Musiker and Odama at https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/gcobb/REU_MCMC/papers.html deals with the situation when the matrices are not symmetric nor traceless, but their technique can be adapted to the present situation to give an answer of sorts, but not a very interesting one.

Answer (score 8):

For fixed $k$, the problem of counting $k$-regular labeled graphs is not intractable at all; the counting sequence is P-recursive, so in principle the sequence is (up to a constant factor) as easy to compute as it could be. (But the complexity grows quickly with $k$.)

For $k\le 5$, see 
I. P. Goulden and D. M. Jackson, Labelled graphs with  small vertex degrees and P-recursiveness. 
SIAM J. Algebraic Discrete Methods 7 (1986),  60-66.

and for P-recursiveness in the general case see my paper

Ira M. Gessel, Symmetric functions and P-recursiveness. 
J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 53 (1990), 257-285.

Comment: Hi @Ira Gessel, I was curious if there is any known closed form formula for enumerating labelled 2-regular graphs ?

Comment: As Vince Vatter noted in his comment, 2-regular labeled graphs are counted by A001205 in the OEIS. There is an explicit formula there as a double sum. It's unlikely that there's a simpler formula.