# Probability that a random multigraph is simple

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, bipartite-graphs, sampling

**Question.**

Consider a *given* sequence of $n$ integers $d_1$, $d_2$, $\cdots$, $d_n$ with $\sum_i d_i$ even and $d_i\le n$ for all $i$. One may sample a random multi-graph having this degree sequence using the (classical) configuration model.

How to compute or precisely estimate **the probability to obtain a *simple* graph** (no loop, no multi-edge)?

For instance, if the sequence is $1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3$ (thus $n=6$), then the probability *experimentally* seems close to $0.016$.

**Remark.**

Classical results (Erdös-Gallai and Havel-Hakimi) tell if a given sequence may lead to a simple graph (graphic sequences). Therefore, they tell (in linear time) if the probability under concern is non-zero.

**Related work.**

There are beautiful asymptotic results for the probability under concern, see in particular Janson papers and van der Hofstad book.

There are also beautiful results based on properties of the sequence, in particular for regular graphs (all $d_i$ are equal) and bounded sequences (the maximal $d_i$ is lower than a given bound). See in particular McKay and Wormald works.

These results hold for families of graphs and consider limits when $n$ grows to infinity, and/or families of sequences of which properties can be specified (like maximum degree bounded by a power of $n$).

**Warning.**

This is *not* the situation I face: I do have one specific sequence and want to estimate the probability that the configuration model gives a simple graph **for this specific sequence**.

**Related questions.**

Is there a way to compute this probability in linear time and space, with respect to $n$?

If, instead of just one sequence, I have *two* sequences of integers (of same sum) and sample *bipartite* multi-graphs with the configuration model, what is the probability to obtain a simple bipartite graph (no multi-edge)?

Comment: I wonder whether the probability is really well-defined without some knowledge as to the properties of your specific sequence?

Comment: @gmvh I may better define it as the fraction of multi-graphs with this degree sequence that are simple.

Comment: I think that @gmvh is asking about realizable degrees sequences. For example a degree sequence 1,2 does not corresponds to any graph. So the fraction is not well-defined.

Comment: Hi Matthieu! I'm not quite clear what you need. You say you want to estimate the probability, and you say $n$ is huge, and as you say there are asymptotic results - so presumably you are in some regime where you think these asymptotic results don't give a good estimate? Is your probability close to 0, or close to 1, or somewhere moderate in between? If the expected number of self-edges and multiple edges is small, a Poisson approximation is typically good. But if it's high, and you want a better estimate than "near 0", then different methods are needed. We may need more details....

Comment: @Sergey, thank you. I think I just need that $\sum_i d_i$ is odd, in order to make sure that there is at least one multi-graph with this sequence. Then, if there is no simple graph with this sequence (it is not realizable, or not graphic), the probability is just 0, right?

Comment: Hi @James! Yes, I do think (or at least, fear) that available asymptotic results do not give good enough estimates for my use. My probability is >0, since I know the sequence is realizable. It is <1 since I know not all graphs with this sequence are simple. I think it is "close to 0", but I need to know how close. For instance, $10^{-9}$ and $10^{-12}$ make a big difference to me.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but it seems that there are some degree sequences with no corresponding graphs at all, nor simple, nor multi. For instance, if we have a degree sequence "1, 2" then, at the best, we will have two connected nodes and a dangling link attached to the one of them. Thus it makes a fraction 0/0 with undefined value... Would your case imply the existence of at least one graph realizing the given degree sequence ?

Comment: Yes @Sergey, but if the sum of degrees is **even** then there is always a possible multi-graph. Sorry, I wrote 'odd' instead of 'even' in my previous reply :/

Comment: That already helps narrow it down. But maybe not enough? - I doubt there is anything off-the-shelf in general, which covers all the cases you might be talking about. I imagine the case of $n$ vertices each of degree $\log(n)$ needs a different approach to that of $1$ vertex of degree $n^{3/4}$ and $n-1$ of degree $2$. So probably we would need to engage more with the specifics of your problem! (But I may be too pessimistic; if so, others may be able to jump in....)

Comment: Sure @James, but since I have only a few and quite different empirical degree sequences, I do not have any model of them, so saying if the maximal degree is $\log(n)$, $\sqrt{n}$, or a constant seems difficult. Still, the number of edges is small compared to $n^2$ and the maximum degree is "large", although significantly smaller than $n$...

Comment: A random matching looks more or less like a bunch of random edges of the right density (I.e. edges selected independently) without 2-paths. In the latter model it’s easy to calculate the probability of no loop or multiple edge, since everything is independent. The models will give about the same answer (up to smallish constants) provided degrees grow with n but the sum of squared degrees is not too fast growing. Is your sequence like that?

Comment: Since the number of configurations is easy to compute, and each simple graph (with given degrees) corresponds to the same number of configurations, what you are asking for is just the number of simple graphs. I'm not aware of a fast way to bound that number rigorously.

Comment: It seems that counting labeled simple regular graphs is already not trivial. There is a bit of discussion on MO : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135293/number-of-labeled-regular-graphs-on-n-vertices

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, the problem is indeed equivalent to computing the number of simple graphs, and I do fear too that there is no satisfactory solution known. I thought that maybe having the exact degree sequence and being open to a somewhat complex algorithmic computation may help, but, as Sergey points out, there is no simple solution even for regular graphs :/

Comment: Matthieu, you have probably already considered this approach. But or the sake of completeness, let me indicate a possible "empirical argument" that consists in sampling several graphs with the specific degree distribution, see how many among them are simple and compare this estimate with Poisson approximation, for example one from  Corollary 3.7
of https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~novozhil/Teaching/767%20Data/47_pdfsam_notes.pdf

Comment: You are right, @Sergey, and this is what I did for the small example in the question above. But for large instances, this is intractable, in particular if the case where the probability is very small. For small instances that I tested, unsurprisingly, the empirical observation is quite different from the asymptotic estimate.

Comment: Does Thm 5.2 of http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/nickcount.pdf match your experiments better?

Comment: Thank you @BrendanMcKay for this interesting reference that I missed. The asymptotic formula of Theorem 5.2 did not help, but I can make experiments on very small examples only, and for rather simple degree sequences. Therefore, I do not know what sense they make. I am more and more thinking that an appropriate approach would be to seek upper and lower bounds, that may be empirically "tight enough".

Comment: A related question was posted recently here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379153/simple-graphs-with-prescribed-degrees-as-disjoint-union-of-simple-subgraphs-with/379427